# Converting binary string to text in R (salesforce ID conversion 15 to 18)

Tags: r, dplyr, salesforce

Looking to create a conversion of a 15 digit salesforce ID to 18 digit in R. The formula is written out here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27686/how-can-i-convert-a-15-char-id-value-into-an-18-char-id-value
but that is in C#, and I'd like to do this in R.

I've made a clunky formula with as much as I know in R which does work for a 15 digit input and returns the 18 digit one successfully. I would like to know how to then apply this to a column in a data.frame via dplyr.

reproducible code:

```
SFID_Convert <- function(fifteen_digit) {
  if (length(fifteen_digit == 15)) {

    # binary map ----
    binary <-
      c(
        "00000",
        "00001",
        "00010",
        "00011",
        "00100",
        "00101",
        "00110",
        "00111",
        "01000",
        "01001",
        "01010",
        "01011",
        "01100",
        "01101",
        "01110",
        "01111",
        "10000",
        "10001",
        "10010",
        "10011",
        "10100",
        "10101",
        "10110",
        "10111",
        "11000",
        "11001",
        "11010",
        "11011",
        "11100",
        "11101",
        "11110",
        "11111"
      )
    letter <- c(LETTERS, 0:5)
    binarymap <- data_frame(binary, letter)


    # sfid ----
    sfid <- substr(fifteen_digit, 1, 15)
    s1 <- substr(sfid, 1, 5)
    s2 <- substr(sfid, 6, 10)
    s3 <- substr(sfid, 11, 15)

    convertID <- function(str_frag) {
      str_frag <- paste(rev(strsplit(str_frag, NULL)[[1]]), collapse = '')
      str_frag <- strsplit(str_frag, NULL)[[1]]
      str_frag[which(unlist(gregexpr("[0-9]", str_frag)) == 1)] <- 0
      str_frag[which(unlist(gregexpr("[a-z]", str_frag)) == 1)] <- 0
      str_frag[which(unlist(gregexpr("[A-Z]", str_frag)) == 1)] <- 1
      str_frag <<- paste(str_frag, collapse = '')
    }

    convertID(s1)
    n1 <- str_frag
    convertID(s2)
    n2 <- str_frag
    convertID(s3)
    n3 <- str_frag

    binary <- data_frame(c(n1, n2, n3)) %>%
      select(binary = 1) %>%
      left_join(binarymap)

    return(paste(sfid, paste(binary$letter[1:3], collapse = ''), sep = ''))}
}
```

example:

```
sfid <- "001a003920aSDuh"
SFID_Convert(sfid)
[1] "001a003920aSDuhAAG"
```

which is what I want, but when you apply it to a df...

```
col <- c("001a003920aSDuh", "001a08h010JNkJd")
name <- c("compA", "compB")
df <- data_frame(name, col)
```

It takes the "AAG" that it correctly computed for the first one, and applies it to every row. I could `lapply` it across, but if I have a df of 100,000 rows, it would be the wrong way to do it I think.

Any help is appreciated! still learning here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various issues with your code. I've included a possible solution below, which should be more efficient:

**1: Defining the map between binary string & letters.** You can do this outside your function. Just define it once, with all the transformations necessary, & use it in the function.

```
binary <- c("00000","00001","00010","00011","00100","00101","00110","00111",
            "01000","01001","01010","01011","01100","01101","01110","01111",
            "10000","10001","10010","10011","10100","10101","10110","10111",
            "11000","11001","11010","11011","11100","11101","11110","11111")
binary.reverse <- lapply(binary, function(x){paste0(rev(strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]]), collapse = "")})
binary2letter <- c(LETTERS, 0:5)
names(binary2letter) <- unlist(binary.reverse)
rm(binary, binary.reverse)
```

I reversed the binary strings in this step as well, so that I don't have to do it repeatedly for all the IDs. The results are saved in a named vector rather than a data frame.

**2: Creating the function in a way that accepts vectors as input.** Note that to check whether a string has X characters, you should use `nchar()` rather than `length()`. The latter returns the number of *strings*, not the number of characters in a string.

```
SFID_Convert <- function(sfid) {
  sfid <- as.character(sfid) # in case the input column are factors

  str_num <- gsub("[A-Z]", "1", gsub("[a-z0-9]", "0", sfid))

  s1 <- substring(str_num, 1, 5)
  s2 <- substring(str_num, 6, 10)
  s3 <- substring(str_num, 11, 15)

  sfid.addon <- paste0(sfid,
                       binary2letter[s1], 
                       binary2letter[s2], 
                       binary2letter[s3])

  sfid[nchar(sfid)==15] <- sfid.addon[nchar(sfid)==15]

  return(sfid)
}
```

Check the solution:

```
sfid <- "001a003920aSDuh"
col <- c("001a003920aSDuh", "001a08h010JNkJd")
name <- c("compA", "compB")
df <- data_frame(name, col)

> SFID_Convert(sfid)
[1] "001a003920aSDuhAAG"

> df %>% mutate(new.col = SFID_Convert(col))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   name             col            new.col
  <chr>           <chr>              <chr>
1 compA 001a003920aSDuh 001a003920aSDuhAAG
2 compB 001a08h010JNkJd 001a08h010JNkJdAAL
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I'll try it out when I get home. I'm trying to find ways to make my code more efficient. One thought on having the binary map outside the function. If I want to add it to a personal package I frequently use, I would want to nest it inside right? (That's why I did it in the first place)

Comment: In my (limited) experience with personal packages, I've written functions that used other helper functions in the same package, so I don't think there's a need for a function to be completely self-contained. But you may wish to ask that as a separate question on SO & get more opinions.

Comment: Valid and fair response. I'll do that. Thanks! Kind of blindly working through this all and learning as I go. I'm sure I'm rife with inefficiencies but whatever! Thanks for the help